# how to access the components of a composite outside its defined method

Tags: swt, jface

I have a method called creatcomponents() where I am creating few text fields and buttons in a composite. Now I want to write listeners to the button which calls a method and in this method I have get the values of the text fields. The problem I am facing is I am unable to access textfields from the method called in the listeners. Can someone help me on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to save the controls are fields in your class:

```java
public class MyClass
{
  private Text text1;
  private Text text2;

  public void createComponents(Composite parent)
  {
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.None);

    text1 = new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE);

    text2 = new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE);

    text1.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
     {
       @Override
       public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event)
       {
         // Access field
         String text = text1.getText();
       }
     });
  }
}
```

Also note that many of the event classes passed to listeners have a `widget` field which refers to the current control which you can also use:

```java
text1.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
 {
   @Override
   public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event)
   {
     Text control = (Text)event.widget;
     String text = control.getText();
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks greg, If I call a method say save() in the modifyText and in the menthod save If I want to disable the text field will the text field be accesiible?

Comment: If `save` is a method of `MyClass` then yes that is OK.